# Is it possible to reconcile github and docutils buildhtml?

Tags: python, github, restructuredtext, docutils

Github will parse a reStructuredText file if its extension is `.rst`. The docutils `buildhtml.py` will only parse files with the extension `.txt`, and I can't see an option to change that. This is massively annoying. Is there any way to get Github to recognise `.txt` files as RST or buildhtml to recognise `.rst` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can just use a symlink?

Comment: Seems like that would *seriously* clutter your source tree, plus not all operating systems support symlinks, so you could be introducing more problems than you're addressing especially since it's a github related issue.

Answer (score 0):

[`buildhtml.py`](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/tools/buildhtml.py) appears to just be a directory walker wrapped around docutils' internals.  Considering its small size, the simplest solution is probably to just modify it to suit your needs by replacing the `.txt` test with a `.rst` test.

Comment: Yeah I was looking for something out-of-the-box (trying to find a solution that's compatible with automatic environment configuration without too much hassle).